# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando cambiar de pantalla cuando hago el build en mi app y al entrar a la condicion que hace el cambio de pantalla me marca el error y depues me cambia de pantalla depues de unos segundos.
Cuando el codigo es 3 es cuando se dispara el error.

```
Widget _futureList(BuildContext context) {
    final entrada = Provider.of<DatosEntradas>(context, listen: true);
    if (entrada.isEmpty && response == null) {
      responseEntradas(entrada);
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (!entrada.isEmpty)
      return _list(context, entrada.datos!);
    else if (response!.entradas.length == 1) {
      String? codigo = response!.entradas[0].codigo;
      if (codigo == "3")
        return microTask();
      else if (codigo == '100' && response!.entradas[0].comportamiento == '6') {
        return _accept();
      } else
        return Center(child: Text(response!.entradas[0].message!));
    } else
      return Center(child: Text('Hubo un error'));
  }
```

```
  microTask() {
    Future.microtask(() => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/permiso'));
    return;
  }
```

Error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: abajo del microtask retorna al menos un widget vacío :  

return;  , sería :   return SizedBox();

Comment: Dentro de `futureList` debes retornar algo fuera de todas las condiciones que tienes. Puede ser simplemente un `Container()`.

Answer (score 0):

Para que te deje de salir el error, retorna un widget vacío en la función donde mandas a llamar a la nueva pantalla:

```
 microTask() {
Future.microtask(() => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/permiso'));
return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
```

}

con eso ya no debería botarte algún error.